# Save multiple images from drawable folder with one button click

Tags: java, android-studio, drawable, android-storage

I want to download multiple images from my app `drawable` with one button click and save it in device `internal/external` storage of my Android app.

How do I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I tried it, but I'm having one issue.

```
 downloadTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            //path here is for internal storage (Option 2), replace it with the other line above from Option 1 to save images to SD card
            String path = new File(getFilesDir(), "/Space Wallpapers").getAbsolutePath();

            //ids are drawables resource ids
            int[] ids = new int[]{ R.drawable.abduction,
                    R.drawable.green_nightstreak,
                    R.drawable.hero,
                    R.drawable.ic_night,
                    R.drawable.light_streak,
                    R.drawable.moon_with_stars,
                    R.drawable.orange_nightstreak,};

            int i = 1;
            for (int res : ids) {
                //Creates the bitmap object from the given resource
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), res);

                File file = new File(path, "image" + i + ".PNG");

                //This creates the file and it's parent if doesn't exist
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOut);
                    fileOut.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                i++;
            }
        };
    });
```

The issue is that it's not the images are not downloading.

**This is what my "Run" log is showing **

```
    D/ViewRootImpl@372fd66[TestActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@372fd66[TestActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.khumomashapa.notes.debug/files/Space Wallpapers/image1.PNG (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1073)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.khumomashapa.notes.debug/files/Space Wallpapers/image2.PNG (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1073)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.khumomashapa.notes.debug/files/Space Wallpapers/image3.PNG (Is a directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1073)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.khumomashapa.notes.debug/files/Space Wallpapers/image4.PNG (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1073)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.khumomashapa.notes.debug/files/Space Wallpapers/image5.PNG (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1073)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.khumomashapa.notes.debug/files/Space Wallpapers/image6.PNG (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1073)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.khumomashapa.notes.debug/files/Space Wallpapers/image7.PNG (Is a directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
W/System.err:     at com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1073)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the IDE & everything to do with the language. Removed/added tags appropriately.

Comment: Well can you copy one image to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "download" you mean save/export. Then, this code should be working fine.

**Option 1:**

If you want to save images to **external** storage (SD card) add this line above the code:

```
String path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Images").getAbsolutePath();
```

**Add**: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to manifest

**Option 2**

If you want to save images to **internal** storage, just add:

```
String path = new File(getFilesDir(), "Images").getAbsolutePath() ;
```

Then:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){

    //path here is for internal storage (Option 2), replace it with the other line above from Option 1 to save images to SD card
    String path = new File(getFilesDir(), "Images").getAbsolutePath();


    //ids are drawables resource ids
    int[] ids = new int[]{R.drawable.imageId1, R.drawable.imageId2, R.drawable.imageId3};

    int i = 1;
    for (int res : ids) {
        //Creates the bitmap object from the given resource
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), res);

        File file = new File(path, "image" + i + ".PNG");

        //This creates the file and it's parent if doesn't exist
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOut);
            fileOut.close;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        i++;
    }
});
```

**Output:**

`R.drawable.imageId1` will be saved to `path/image1.PNG`

`R.drawable.imageId2` will be saved to `path/image2.PNG`

`R.drawable.imageId3` will be saved to `path/image3.PNG`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to say. How do I link this to a button so that when it's clicked it starts the save/export.

Comment: See my updated answer, I put the code inside a OnClick event of a `Button`

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to create any variables or references?

Comment: You're welcome! First initialise `yourButton` or replace it with the `Button` in your activity that will do the job. Also, replace sample ids `R.drawable.imageId1 `,  `R.drawable.imageId2 `,  `R.drawable.imageId3 ` with your actual drawable ids from your project.

Comment: I've done that, but now I'm getting errors. The "fOut" and "close" are giving me a "Cannot resolve symbol". Did I make a mistake or I'm I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled fileOut and forgot try/catch block. Now it's complete

Comment: Okay. I just fixed those. Now I've got one error again, but it's this line. fileOut.close. It's still saying Cannot resolve symbol 'close'

Comment: Please make sure that if `fileOut.close` is inside try/catch block, and that you copy paste the exact same code directly. If error still exist, post your code to the question at the top.

Comment: Well, it's another miss from me :), I should have called `file.getParentFile().mkdirs();` instead of `file.mkdirs();`. I have edited my answer again. **Note:** before running this code remove all previous directories with names image1.PNG image2.PNG ... in folder `/Space Wallpapers`

Comment: I've made the changes, but it's still not working. Let me post the code I currently have

Comment: Have you deleted directories I've mentioned in the comment earlier?

Comment: Yes. I deleted them

Comment: It's okay dude. I fixed the problem. For physical device was the problem. It wouldn't allow any apps to grant permissions including mine. Thank you for your help

Comment: Finally! It's been a long journey, Kindly mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks.